# Adding a counter_cache column on the version model for the Paper Trail gem

Tags: paper-trail-gem

I have a `Page` model with PT configured. I also have a `Versions::PageVersion` model because page versions are stored in a separate table (`page_versions`). The `Page` model has a column for counter cache, called `page_versions_count`. So far, everything is pretty standard.

To make the counter cache work, I've overwritten the `belongs_to :item` association on the version model, which looks as follows:

```rb
class Versions::PageVersion < PaperTrail::Version
  belongs_to :item,
             polymorphic: true,
             counter_cache: true
end
```

This actually works, but I'm wondering now if that's the right way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PT does not provide a way to configure the `belongs_to :item` association. The association options are hard-coded in [paper_trail/version_concern.rb:18](https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail/blob/master/lib/paper_trail/version_concern.rb#L18).

AFAICT, re-defining an association, as you have done, is supported by AR. The new options (including `counter_cache`) replace (rather than merge with) the old options. I've confirmed this experimentally using `ActiveRecord::Reflection`, but can't find official docs acknowledging this.

So, your solution is the best that I can think of.

If you'd like to contribute your solution to the docs, I'd happily review a PR. I'd suggest somewhere near section "5.b. Configuring the versions Association".

Comment: Thanks, Jared! That reassuring. I'll create a PR with the example above.